# How to extract meta description in mysql according to keyword in search engine

Tags: php, mysql

Can we display a description of the site that is adjusted to the keyword of the site visitors while in the search engine.

For example, I have an article like this in the `description` table:

> a bb ccc dddd eeeee ffffff ggggggg
>
> h ii jjj kkkk lllll mmmmmm nnnnnnn
>
> o pp qqq rrrr sssss tttttt uuuuuuu

Well when someone shoots the keyword `ffffff` (`google.com/search?q=ffffff`) then the search results of the machine will be:

```
<meta name="description" content="a bb ccc dddd eeeee ffffff ggggggg" />
```

Whereas if the person shoots the keyword `tttttt` (`google.com/search?q=tttttt`) then the engine search results will:

```
<meta name="description" content="o pp qqq rrrr sssss tttttt uuuuuuu" />
```

For example on blogspot, there create a unique meta description in accordance with the keyword that was shot. So the keyword that is shot will appear while still in the search engine.

Can it do it using PHP?

Comment: They aren't reacting "live" when the search occurs. The description in google/bing/etc. is stored on the search engine's server, and isn't retrieved from your site during the search or the display of results. Sites like blogspot tailor the description for a post based on the keywords used with the particular page on the site.

Comment: So there is no way to do that?

Comment: Where do you think you would get the info about what they searched? It isn't passed to your site by any of the search engines. All you can do is have relevant keywords and descriptions on every page on your site.

Comment: Is this not called keyword stuffing? In which case it would do your sites google rank more harm than good

Comment: Oh ok, I get it now :)